# Swapping datapoints in dataframe in R studio

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing some QC on some data and I want to swap some points in R, rather than on the actual dataset itself.

here is the head

```
  ZEMA.pot B         C           I    Diff                  ifelse(Diff > 1, "OK", "CHECK")
1       11 -36.90 -26.88         CA  0.7284553                           CHECK
2       12 -27.90 -36.63         CA 1.3129032                              OK
3       13 -27.08 -34.71         CA 1.2817578                              OK
```

I am simply trying to switch the values of B and C where the last column says "CHECK"
I tried to get fancy with some ifelse statements, but I can't seem to get it to work where I swap the values (so for the first row I idally want B to be -26.88 and C to be -36.90)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dplyr library as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(ZEMA.pot=c(11,12,13),
                   B=c(-36.9,-27.9,-27.08),
                   C=c(-26.88,-36.63,-34.71),
                   I=c("CA","CA","CA"),
                   Diff=c(0.7, 1.3, 1.2))

# Swap by specific criteria on Diff field
duplicateData1 <- data %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(Diff > 1, B, NA),
         B = ifelse(Diff > 1, C, B),
         C = ifelse(Diff > 1, temp, C)) %>%
  select(-temp)

# Swap by specific criteria on ZEMA.pot field
duplicateData2 <- data %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(ZEMA.pot == 12, B, NA),
         B = ifelse(ZEMA.pot == 12, C, B),
         C = ifelse(ZEMA.pot == 12, temp, C)) %>%
  select(-temp)

# Swap by specific row number
duplicateData3 <- data %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(row_number() == 3, B, NA),
         B = ifelse(row_number() == 3, C, B),
         C = ifelse(row_number() == 3, temp, C)) %>%
  select(-temp)

# Swap by random row number
nrows <- nrow(data)
randomRowNumber <- floor(runif(1, min=1, max=nrows))
duplicateData4 <- data %>%
  mutate(temp = ifelse(row_number() == randomRowNumber, B, NA),
         B = ifelse(row_number() == randomRowNumber, C, B),
         C = ifelse(row_number() == randomRowNumber, temp, C)) %>%
  select(-temp)
```

Comment: Interesting, is there any way to do it on a row by row basis, though?  The >1 is just a criterion, not neccessarily  going to want to swap every single one of them

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact criteria for swapping is, but I've added a few different options to the answer.